# I need my .htaccess file to redirect all <any_name>.php to <same_name>.html except for index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need an .htaccess rewrite rule that will redirect links like this:

- www.mydomain.com/viewpressrelease.php
- www.mydomain.com/viewpressrelease.php?id=17 (or any text follwing .php)
- www.mydomain.com/employment.php

to links with the same name replacing .php to .html like this:

- www.mydomain.com/viewpressrelease.html
- www.mydomain.com/employment.html

but not act on the index.php or the following:

- www.mydomain.com/administrator/index.php

I have an example that is close but does not handle ?id=17 part and is making index.php into index.html.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s 
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

What do I need to make this work as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to exclude `index.php` and then remove the last `\s` from the check against `%{THE_REQUEST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Comment: @Rassilon You should check the green checkmark next to the answer so your question is marked as resolved.